# Power System Economics Generation Dispatch Calculation

Tags: power, system, power-generation

[image: Marginal Cost Equations]

[image: Part B Question]

Assuming that the annuitised investment cost of transmission link is 37 € /MW.km.year, calculate the network annual cost and annual network profit for the three proposed cases.

I'm trying to calculate the generation dispatches for the first scenario where the North Load is 60MW, South Load is 300MW and transmission link capacity is 60MW.

I'm not too sure how to go about it but I've attempted an optimisation problem where you:

[image: Optimisation equations]

This is my answer from a solver: G1 = 48.3333, G2 = 11.6666, G3 = 156, G4 = 144, F = 0. I'm kind of suspicious given that the transmission flow is 0. Can anyone check my answer or suggest a better approach for calculating the generation dispatches given that I have to repeat the math another 20+ times.

Comment: The constraint equations I uploaded are incorrect, it should be P1 + P2 - F = 60 and P3 + P4 + F = 300, and 0 <= F <= 60.